# Jsoup - getting a HTML tag with ONLY the specified attributes and its values

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I want to use `jsoup` to extract elements from a page that have *only* some specific attributes and values. I have gone through the below mentioned methods and none solved my purpose well:

1. Jsoup's `getElementsByAttributesMatching`
2. This format of select query:

   ```
   doc.select("table[width=100%]").select("table[cellpadding=0]").select("table[cellspacing=0]");
   ```
3. This one too:

   ```
   doc.select("table[width=100%][cellpadding=0][cellspacing=0]");
   ```

When I use these methods I am getting elements which have the attributes I have mentioned plus other attributes too. What I want are the elements with ONLY the specified attributes.

Is there a way to get pass this huddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector already select element having a specific value for those *3* attributes. So the element has at least 3 attributes. But if it has *exactly* 3 attributes, then those are the ones you specified.

```
for (Element el: doc.select("table[width=100%][cellpadding=0][cellspacing=0]"))
    if (el.attributes().size() == 3)
        // Do something
```

---

### Example

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(
    "<table width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>OK</table>" +
    "<table width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 height=100%>NO</table>");

for (Element el: doc.select("table[width=100%][cellpadding=0][cellspacing=0]"))
    if (el.attributes().size() == 3)
        System.out.println(el.text());
```

*Output*

```
OK
```