# Unset td padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, extjs, aem

I'm working with AEM CMS and the user can build a table in a rich text editor. It works pretty well. Our implementation also uses bootstrap 3.1. Bootstrap sets td and th padding to 0. This takes precedence over the cellpadding set by the system based on the user's settings for the table compoonent. The generated HTML looks like this. The users' setting for cell padding was set to 4 in this example...

```
<div class="parbase table">
  <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>Hello 1</td>
      <td>Hello2</td>
      <td>Hello3&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lsdvn dfijkn jsdvoi m orijojnl JDFIUJ</td>
      <td>adfbsk ik</td>
      <td>lsdvn dfijkn jsdvoi m orijojnl JDFIUJ</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Using Chrome Inspect Element I can see the Bootstrap rule is applied. When I uncheck this rule the table cellpadding takes effect, and the td's look good.

```
td, th {
  padding: 0;
}
```

I've tried to remove the rule using initial and unset, but neither worked.

```
td, th {
  padding: initial; /* and unset */
}
```

I'm hoping there's a css solution that doesn't involved changing the implementation of the component code generating the table html. Also, since we use a CDN for the bootstrap css/js, I don't want to customize the framework either.

Hopefully there's a CSS solution such that the bootstrap td and th padding rule can be unset/removed/deleted/etc.

Comment: according to https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input initial is value for padding. your right that unset is not, though I thought based on this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset it was worth a try.

Comment: You’re right, CSS3 has introduced `initial`, http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-cascade/#initial But that won’t help you here, because that would just reset the padding to its initial value, with is `0` – and therefor it would have the same effect as setting the padding to `0` explicitly, which you already discovered doesn’t help achieve what you’re after there. (And `unset` for padding would again just mean `initial`, because padding does not get inherited.)

Comment: What's with the ExtJS tag?

Comment: Extjs is the ui library with the rich text editor and it also builds the html table

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a more specific rule, which if I'm not mistaken will take priority over any less specific rule:

```
div.parbase td {
  padding: 4px;
}
```

If this works, you can take out the cellpadding property of the table.

Comment: I think he should assign a class to that table and use it in the css so that it overrides the style for that specific table and not every table in the div element (unless that's what he wants to do). He can also use !important to make sure it will always use that rule.

Comment: The system places the user setting in the table cellpadding attribute. Doing your suggestion isn't really possible for me because the user settings cannot be output in CSS. Perhaps I could do it inline, but was hoping not to change the table implementation.

Comment: Can the system set the style property on TDs based on the value? It'll look cluttered but it should work:
<td style="padding:4px;">

Comment: In the end, I combined the approach suggested by Eraph (doing inline on the tr) and Gabs (setting tr and td padding to inherit). cellpadding isn't valid html5 so they render with specificity of 0, and any padding style will take precedence. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369271/css-precedence-of-standalone-attributes-like-cellpadding https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/html-parser-service.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228373/jsoup-getting-a-html-tag-with-only-the-specified-attributes-and-its-values

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using jQuery `cssText` function:

```
$("td, th").css("cssText", "padding: 0 !important;");
```

This will override the rule after it.

Comment: bootstrap already sets the padding to 0. I'm trying to get around that. It seems if padding is not specified at all, then cellspacing would take effect. In Chrome, when I uncheck the bootstrap rule, I see padding is computed based on the cellspacing attribute